# SQL join is duplicating data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
`SELECT 
t2.Date, 
t2.CampaignID,
t1.CampaignName,
SUM(t2.Impressions) AS Impressions,
SUM(t2.Clicks) AS Clicks,
SUM(t2.Cost/1000000) AS Cost,
SUM(t2.Conversions) AS Conversions
FROM "table_1.Campaign_5333142620" t1
LEFT JOIN "table_1.CampaignBasicStats_5333142620" t2 USING (CampaignId)
WHERE t2.DATE = '2022-02-09' AND t2.CampaignID = 15917662281
GROUP BY t2.Date, t1.CampaignName, t2.CampaignID
LIMIT 10`
```

Hey all,

I am having an issue whereby my data is exactly duplicated for each row when performing this join. Without the join, using the table "CampaignBasicStats", the data is not duplicated, but joining to the other table creates the duplication...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: then you are either missing a join column or there is some other duplication going on.  Can't say without seeing the table definitions, sample data, and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try on this way..

`SELECT  t2.Date,  t2.CampaignID, t1.CampaignName, SUM(t2.Impressions) AS Impressions, SUM(t2.Clicks) AS Clicks, SUM(t2.Cost/1000000) AS Cost, SUM(t2.Conversions) AS Conversions FROM "table_1.Campaign_5333142620" t1 LEFT JOIN "table_1.CampaignBasicStats_5333142620" t2 ON t2.CampaignId = t1.CampaignId AND t2.DATE = '2022-02-09' AND t2.CampaignID = 15917662281 GROUP BY t2.Date, t1.CampaignName, t2.CampaignID LIMIT 10`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).